# Android SDK Library - Where is it?

Tags: android, sdk

I can't seem to find the location of my Android SDK Library. Android Studio keeps asking me to specify the location of it and I can't seem to find it on my machine. I also can't seem to download the Android SDK either as it's meant to come alongside Android Studio.

I've Uninstalled and Installed - still no luck.

I am using Mac.

Any ideas?

Comment: you most likely downloaded the sdk installer

Answer (score 1):

Tools>Android>SDK manager and make sure everything is downloaded

Comment: Where is that in Mac?

Comment: Tools should be one of the menus at the top of your screen

Comment: No no. Not the SDK manager. The actual SDK folder that is used by Android Studio. i.e. for Projects.

Comment: inside your android studio folder, there should be a folder called sdk?

Comment: There isn't. I checked in Application > Android Studio >

Comment: are you sure you have clicked android sdk manager and installed the latest version of the sdk??